# Android Studio: suppress lint warning for if statement

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, suppress-warnings

I have a this code somewhere in my Android project:

```
public boolean isLoadInProgress(boolean privateLoad, boolean publicLoad) {
    if (privateLoad && privateLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    if (publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I get a lint warning at the second if statement: 'if' statement could be simplified. That's obviously because I could write as well:

```
return publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress;
```

However, I would like to keep it this way for readability. I know that there is some inline comment annotation for switching off the lint warning at that place, but I can't find it in the [Android Lint documentation](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings). Can you tell me what this annotation/comment was?

Comment: This link has all the lint ids http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Comment: Are you sure it's lint? Looks like the sort of thing that Android Studio/IntelliJ would flag up.

Comment: imo, removing the redundant if-statement improves readability and I would go for `return (privateLoad && privateLoadInProgress || publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress);`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simple code comment for disabling the warning is:

```
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
```

This on top of the if-statement should switch off the warning only at that place.

In the example, this would be:

```
public boolean isLoadInProgress(boolean privateLoad, boolean publicLoad) {
    if (privateLoad && privateLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("SimplifiableIfStatement")` above your method.

Answer (score 10):

It's not an Android Lint error. You can use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("RedundantIfStatement")
public static boolean isLoadInProgress(boolean privateLoad, boolean publicLoad) {
    if (privateLoad && privateLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    if (publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

At the highlighted `if`, you can use the alt-enter shortcut to open the context menu and select `Simplify > Suppress for method` (keeping the scope as small as possible).

Comment: Although the accepted answer `//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement` doesn't seem to resolve the Lint warning described in the question, or at least it didn't in my case, it does show that you can further narrow the suppression scope with this answer by putting the suppression code/comment directly on top of the specific IF statement with the Lint warning, like this: `//noinspection RedundantIfStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

> In .java files, you can suppress issues with the @SuppressLint
>   annotations. You supply the lint issue id as the argument to the
>   annotations.

Example:

```
@SuppressLint("AndroidWarningId")
public boolean isLoadInProgress(boolean privateLoad, boolean publicLoad) {
    if (privateLoad && privateLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    if (publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just replace the AndroidWarningId with the corresponding warning, you can find those in [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)

Although I would suggest simplifying it this way:

```
public boolean isLoadInProgress(boolean privateLoad, boolean publicLoad) {
    if (privateLoad && privateLoadInProgress
     || publicLoad && publicLoadInProgress) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Its still readable and uses less space (kind of ugly though, but better than a supresslint).

You can also suppress more than one issue using a comma separated list:

> @SuppressLint({"NewApi","StringFormatInvalid"})

Cheers!